# one Field for 2 parameters in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

```
public ArrayList searchCustomer(String cid) throws SQLException {


ArrayList searchCustList = new ArrayList();



PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from customer where (custID = ? OR firstName LIKE ?)");


 pStmt.setString(1, cid);


pStmt.setString(2, "%" + cid + "%");
```

please explain last command i used one text field for search customer  by name or ID can any body explain last line

Comment: Your question is unclear explain it properly

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear,  but if you want to understand :`pStmt.setString(2, "%" + cid + "%");`

Then it set the second parameter in sql query to  the value of cid variable, and add % around

Adding `%` around, mean in an SQL Like 'any character', so having `%cid%`  mean anything containing  cid in it.

As the actual query use  cid for either custId or firstName, it mean that it look for user having a specific id, or having in its firstname the id.

Which is strange, and looks like more a bug, than a logical query, but maybe it come from old legacy having some id in firstname, who knows

Comment: @Masud yes, cid is a variable, and will be replaced by its value in the query. It was just a quick explanation, and i hope that the concept of variable name and variable value is known ;)